# Overriding disabled input and textarea with CSS

Tags: css

Im trying to override the grey text of a disabled input and textarea. At the moment Im only really concerned with it working in Webkit and Mozilla. At the moment Im currently using every trick in the book that I know of:

```
input[@disabled=true], input[@disabled],
button[disabled]:active, button[disabled],
input[type="reset"][disabled]:active,
input[type="reset"][disabled],
input[type="button"][disabled]:active,
input[type="button"][disabled],
select[disabled] > input[type="button"],
select[disabled] > input[type="button"]:active,
input[type="submit"][disabled]:active,
input[type="submit"][disabled],input[disabled="disabled"], input[disabled] {
    color: black !important;
}
```

Sure it does change the colour if I change it to something else, however when I choose black it is still greyed out a bit.

Any ideas? I am using Ext JS if I can use that to manipulate it. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Is it something to do with opacity, perhaps? I suggest using Firebug (or cash-equivalent) and checking on the computed style for one of those greyed out disabled inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
input.button-control[disabled]

{

    color: #cccccc !important;

    }
```

Here `button-control` is a class on the input element, whose text is overriden to grey when the disabled attribute is set.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works great in firefox, but i am not able to override the grey default font `color` in IE. Is there a special attribute besides `color` that i need to set. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to go the JavaScript way to achieve best browser compatibility. I would use the ExtJS [http://www.extjs.com/deploy/ext-1.1.1/docs/output/Ext.DomQuery.html][DomQuery] and insert the CSS rules by adding specific class or directly injecting them as style attribute values.